# SVN client not updating file in working copy

Tags: linux, svn

After I update my WC (working copy), one of the files is still in an old revision.

As it can be seen bellow, `svn info` command shows that last changed revison for file getOdSum.php is 403. But it's not true as shown by `svn list` command:

```
host:~# svn info /srv/www/htdocs/services/getOdSum.php
Path: /srv/www/htdocs/services/getOdSum.php
Name: getOdSum.php
Working Copy Root Path: /srv/www
URL: http://blah/www/htdocs/services/getOdSum.php
Repository Root: http://blah
Repository UUID: e8d72a91-f4c2-7648-b7bf-ec66f57ea273
Revision: 593
Node Kind: file
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: dlopez
Last Changed Rev: 403
Last Changed Date: 2018-03-14 18:30:53 +0000 (Wed, 14 Mar 2018)
Text Last Updated: 2018-04-23 19:12:59 +0000 (Mon, 23 Apr 2018)
Checksum: bc9b7ff245aadd45cacc1d11377a0227a08dfe6a
```

The command `svn list` shows that the last changed revision in repository is 537:

```
host:~ # svn list /srv/www/htdocs/services/ --verbose
Authentication realm: <http://blah> SVN Repository
Password for 'dlopez':
    537 dlopez                May 07 20:01 ./
    419 dlopez           1920 Jul 12  2018 getLastMan.php
    537 dlopez          11450 May 07 20:01 getOdSum.php
    383 dlopez             19 Aug 18  2017 info.php
(...)
```

Of course, previously I tried the following commands (where /srv/www is the root WC directory)

```
host:~ #svn cleanup /srv/www

host:~ # svn update /srv/www
Updating '/srv/www':
Authentication realm: <http://blah> SVN Repository
Password for 'dlopez':
At revision 593.

host:~ # svn update /srv/www/htdocs/services/getOdSum.php
Updating '/srv/www/htdocs/services/getOdSum.php':
Authentication realm: <http://blah> SVN Repository
Password for 'dlopez':
At revision 593.
```

Am I doing something wrong or it's a bug in the client?
It's pretty old:

```
host:~ # svn --version
svn, version 1.7.13 (r1516569)

Copyright (C) 2013 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people; see the NOTICE
file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_neon : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using Neon.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
```

I solved it by renaming the WC and doing fresh checkout in a new one, but it would be good to understand the problem.